# Download using wget to a different directory than current directory

Tags: wget

I need to use `wget` to download a file to the directory `/var/cache/foobar/` (so, as an example, if I download `stackexchange-site-list.txt`, it'd be downloaded to `/var/cache/foobar/stackexchange-site-list.txt`)

Is this possible? `curl` would also be an option, but I'd prefer to not use `curl`, since it's not installed by default.

Comment: FYI, This information is available in `man wget`

Comment: @user606723 Can you explain why this got downvotes? It's a legitimate question.

Comment: it's my guess that it was down voted because this is an extremely basic question and would've been solved by any sort of googling or looking in `man get`. The goal of stackexchange isn't to answer every possible question.

Comment: This SO Q&A explains that you can do this using the `-P` switch, same w/ the A below. From the manual page: [How to specify the location with wget?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1078539/33204).

Comment: This is only a basic question to those who already know the answer. To anyone who doesn’t, it is *not* basic. Searching the man pages is not as simple as it sounds because they are quite long and few sane people with lives have the time or wherewithal to sit and read through all of that. The best argument you can make is that the man pages could be filtered with `grep` or something, but even that is not likely to give the answer due to wording.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you know the name of the file ahead of time, you can use the `-O` option to wget to tell it where to write the file.

```
wget -O /var/cache/foobar/stackexchange-site-list.txt http://url.to/stackexchange-site-list.txt
```

Comment: @jrg: You *can* specify a download directory. See [ephemient's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23507/21962).

Comment: right is that -0 or -O, I guess can just copy it and see

Comment: its a `minus capital O` if that helps

Comment: askubuntu's answer sets a new default (with alias in `.bashrc`) without needing to type the command each time: [how to change wget default directory](https://askubuntu.com/a/213529/1024340)

Answer (score 244):

```
wget -P /var/cache/foobar/ [...]
wget --directory-prefix=/var/cache/foobar/ [...]
```

Comment: -P lets wget start creating sub folders depending on how you select options to download.

Comment: -P seems to be the synonym for --directory-prefix. From the manual: ‘-P prefix’
‘--directory-prefix=prefix’
Set directory prefix to prefix. The directory prefix is the directory where all other files and subdirectories will be saved to, i.e. the top of the retrieval tree. The default is ‘.’ (the current directory).

Comment: It seems to be silently & recursively creating the specified directoriy(s), if one either mistyped an actual directory path, or just outright non existent one. Additionally, the long form of the flag `--directory-prefix=`  seems to be either not working correctly with shell expansion, or always ignites every path from the current relative path

Answer (score 1):

```
wget -e robots=off -r --no-parent /home/user/Desktop/MIT/ http://abc.tamu.edu/projects/tzivi/repository/revisions/2/raw/tzivi/
```

To add: The above code would allow you to download ALL files from the targeted directory to the directory of your choice in a single command.

**Break Down of Command:**

The Parameters for which **wget** uses to download the ***entire*** directory at once instead of one file at a time:

```
wget -e robots=off -r --no-parent
```

The Destination of Downloaded Files

```
/home/user/Desktop/MIT/
```

The Origin of Files (Online Directory)

```
http://abc.tamu.edu/projects/tzivi/repository/revisions/2/raw/tzivi/
```