# Using wget on a directory outside the user's home directory

Tags: wget, ftp

I'm trying to mirror a directory via FTP with wget. The command I'm using is

```
wget -m ftp://user:pass@192.168.1.1/foo/bar/
```

But, when I run it, I get the following:

```
--2018-10-10 15:01:32--  ftp://user:*password*@192.168.1.1/foo/bar/
       => ‘192.168.3.150/foo/bar/.listing’
Connecting to 192.168.1.1:21... connected.
Logging in as user ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /usr/user/foo/bar ... 
No such directory ‘foo/bar’.
```

I've searched the man pages, and googled, and I can't figure it out. How do I make wget actually download the directory "/foo/bar/", and not "/usr/user/foo/bar/"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162053/any-way-to-specify-absolute-paths-in-ftp-urls) (which involved java instead of wget, but really the underlying problem is with the URL syntax which is hopefully language-independent) was resolved by adding another slash and URL-encoding it, like this:

```
wget -m ftp://user:pass@192.168.1.1/%2Ffoo/bar/
```

It works for me even without encoding, just with an extra slash:

```
wget -m ftp://user:pass@192.168.1.1//foo/bar/
```

The first slash is thrown away (serving only as a separator between host and path), and the second slash actually counts as part of the path.

Comment: I never even thought about including a second slash in the URL. Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download a specific directory using `wget` like this:

```
wget -m 'ftp://[user]@192.168.1.1/%2ffoo/bar' -O /foo/bar
```

I would avoid putting your password into the URL as it will then appear in your bash history. This command of course means that `/foo/bar` is located off of `/` and not anywhere else. If `/foo/bar` is located off of something like `/var/www` you will need to include the full path in the command.

I take it you are using a UNIX-like based off of the `/usr/user` so there may be differences in the function of the specific implementation of `wget` you are using.

Here is an alternative using `curl`:

```
curl -u [user] 'ftp://192.168.1.1/%2fpath/to/foo/bar' -o /path/to/foo/bar
```

Please read over these links:

[FTP URLs](http://jkorpela.fi/ftpurl.html)
[How to use wget](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/wget-command-with-username-password/)
[Using wget to recursively download FTP directories](https://serverfault.com/questions/25199/using-wget-to-recursively-download-whole-ftp-directories)
[Download using wget to a different directory than current directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23501/download-using-wget-to-a-different-directory-than-current-directory)
[How to specify the location with wget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078524/how-to-specify-the-location-with-wget/1078539#1078539)
[Downloading file from FTP using cURL](https://superuser.com/questions/265062/downloading-file-from-ftp-using-curl)

Please comment if you have any questions or issues with this answer. I highly suggest you read through each link I have provided thoroughly before attempting the commands. I appreciate feedback to correct any misconceptions and to improve my posts. I can update my answer as needed.

Best of Luck!